# C#&Crystal Reports, Failed to Load database error

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

But when I try to run, I got the following exception.
I tried various solutions, but all did fail.

Of course, I added startup code already.
Please give me an idea.

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          SqlConnection con;
          string source = @"Data Source = 1.2.3.4; Initial Catalog = Sales; USER ID = user1; PASSWORD = 87665;";

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.SS where ADM01F = '@sBox'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scBox", SearchTBox.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter adt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.SS where ADM01F = '@sBox'", con);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            adt.Fill(DS);
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            string reportpath = Application.StartupPath + "\\SNIReport.rpt";
            cryRpt.Load(@"C:\SalesReport\SNIReport.rpt");
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(DS);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            con.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
```

Comment: you got the following exception???where is exception?you did not write the exception.

Comment: I don't see you instantiating the `SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(source)` ? (and passing connection string (`source`) to the `con` instance.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see..

You should **not** use single quotes with your parameters. With single quotes, your query see them as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), not a parameter. And you should use *that* command in your `SqlDataAdapter` constructor as a first parameter, not create an another sql query that expects a parameter.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.SS where ADM01F = @sBox", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scBox", SearchTBox.Text);
SqlDataAdapter adt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
```

Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as possible. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

And don't forget to use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and adapsters automatically instead of calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

As mentioned, your `SqlConnection` object does not have any connection string. You either create your object with this parameter as;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
```

or set it's [`ConnectionString` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as;

```
SqlConnection con;
con.ConnectionString = source;
```